# Цикл в Pandas с несколькими DF

Tags: python, циклы, pandas, if, dataframe

Итак, у нас есть исходный DF

```
   x1  x2
0  15  13
1  20 -40
2  25  30
3  20  22
```

И второй DF

```
        Ot    Do  rating
0 -1000000  0.99     0.1
1        1  1.99     0.2
2        2  2.99     0.3
3        3  3.99     0.4
```

Проводим следующие манипуляции (образно) `x1*rating/x2`
далее проверяем условие, если это выражение`<= Do и >=Ot` , то записываем его в список. Если не подходит, то берем второе значение `rating (0,2)` , и опять проверяем, попало ли в диапазон `1: 1.99`, если попало, то на этом заканчиваем цикл с первой парой `x1x2` и переходим ко второй паре.

По приведенным условиям получится такой DF

`x1 x2 rating
15  13 0.1
20  -40 0.1
25  30 0.1
20  22 0.1`

Comment: можете привести в вопросе пример того, что должно получиться на выходе?

Comment: сейчас обновлю.

Comment: не очень удачный пример - лучше привести пример в котором в результате будет 2-3 разных рейтинга и случай когда не найден подходящий диапазон - что делать в этом случае?

Comment: Диапазон всегда будет найден, просто иногда их будет несколько правильных с учетом rating, программа должна взять первый попавшийся

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исходные DataFrame'ы:

```
In [31]: d1
Out[31]:
   x1  x2
0  15  13
1  20 -40
2  25  30
3  20  22

In [32]: d2
Out[32]:
        Ot    Do  rating
0 -1000000  0.99     0.1
1        1  1.99     0.2
2        2  2.99     0.3
3        3  3.99     0.4
```

Решение:

```
def get_rating(val, rdf):
    r = rdf.query("Ot <= @val * rating <= Do")
    if not r.empty:
        return r.iat[0, 2]
    else:
        return None

d1['rating'] = d1.eval("x=x1/x2")['x'].apply(lambda r: get_rating(r, d2))
```

Результат:

```
In [35]: d1
Out[35]:
   x1  x2  rating
0  15  13     0.1
1  20 -40     0.1
2  25  30     0.1
3  20  22     0.1
```